# How to call the lookup columns in Rest API?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to call lookup fields in REST API.

Thanks on Advance

Comment: What is your existing query that you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Krishna,

for retrieving lookups, you should select them and expand them:

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'<guid>')/items?$select=MyLookupField/Title&$expand=MyLookupField
```

This Url will give you the Title of the selected Item in `MyLookupField`. The [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx) is always a good resource for such things

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Here i have 4 lookup column in my list.is it possible to call?

Comment: Yes you can have Multiple Lookup Fields. Simply comma-seperate them in the select and expand part of the query

Answer (score 0):

You will get it by below code

```
/_api/web/lists(guid'<guid>')/items?$select=Title,LookupField1/FieldToBeExpanded1,LookupField2/FieldToBeExpanded2&$expand=LookupField1,LookupField2
```

In example, I just got multiple lookup fields & expand them.

Get further details from below article.

[SharePoint 2013 API OData For Lookup Fields](http://www.ozkary.com/2015/10/sharepoint-2013-api-odata-for-lookup-fields.html)